# Parser Error in this View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Just melt my brain out trying to figure out why I'm getting *Parser Error* with this code:

```
    @foreach(var news in Model.News)
    {
        if (news.Order > 0)
        {
            <text>
    <div class="colPrincipal newsTop newsBlue">
        <article>
            <a href="news.html">
            </text>

            if (news.LayoutExibitionMainImage)
            {
            <text>
                <span class="newsImg">
                    <img src="~/Content/img/news/not2.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                </span>
            </text>
            }

            <text>
                <hgroup>
            </text>

            if (news.LayoutExibitionMainTitle)
            {
            <text>
                    <h1>
                        @Html.Raw(news.Title)
                    </h1>
            </text>
            }

            if (news.LayoutExibitionMainSummary)
            {
            <text>
                    <h2>
                        @Html.Raw(news.Summary)
                    </h2>
            </text>
            }

            <text>
                </hgroup>
                <span class="btnMais">Ler este artigo</span>
            </a>
        </article>
    </div>
            </text>
        }
    }
```

Its throwing this error on my last `<text>` tag:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this or a better way to print that HTML code? I hope this is not a silly question because is wierd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i think you have an issue with all those text tags. Also text is not allowed in the hgroup tags.

```
@foreach(var news in Model.News)
{
        @if (news.Order > 0)
        {
            <div class="colPrincipal newsTop newsBlue">
                <article>
                    <a href="news.html">
                        @if (news.LayoutExibitionMainImage)
                        {
                            <span class="newsImg">
                                <img src="~/Content/img/news/not2.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                            </span>
                        }

                        <hgroup>
                            @if (news.LayoutExibitionMainTitle)
                            {
                                    <h1>
                                        @Html.Raw(news.Title)
                                    </h1>
                            }

                            @if (news.LayoutExibitionMainSummary)
                            {
                                    <h2>
                                        @Html.Raw(news.Summary)
                                    </h2>
                            }
                        </hgroup>
                        <span class="btnMais">Ler este artigo</span>
                    </a>
                </article>
            </div>
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it prints the `if` and other codes like text in the page.

Comment: Damn, it worked with `@` in front of all `if`. Such a silly question. I'll mark your answer anyway. Thank you!